# In the DC universe, how do Zeta Tubes work?

Tags: dc, technology, transportation

In the DC universe, there is a means of travel called the Zeta Tubes.

How do they work (conceptually)?

- Do they copy the info of what's in the origin, destroy its contents, and paste it at the other end?
- Do they separate the body from the soul, copy the body and destroy it, send the soul and info of the body to the destination and reconstruct it, and merge the body with the soul?
- Do they just send the whole thing to another dimension where the speed of light is a lot faster, carry it to the destination equivalent place, and bring it back to the original dimension?
- Another way different than any of the above (please expand on the explanation)?

Comment: https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Zeta-Beam

Comment: @Valorum interesting read, but it doesn’t answer the question asked.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Hence why it's posted as a comment.

Comment: Are adaptations OK, or do you just want the original comics? If so, I tend to imagine you can get a lot of mileage out of *Young Justice*, which used Zeta Tubes extensively for "regular" transportation. IIRC there was never any mention of copies or souls, and nobody ever seemed to have a problem with using them (unlike for example *Star Trek*, which usually had some random person object to the transporters about once per season, at least in TNG and later). But I'm not sure whether they copied that from the comics.